# Reading from a .txt file to a vector of doubles in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read values from a .txt file to a vector (which is a member of a class) in C++, but despite the .txt having around 1000 lines, the vector is of size 0. I inserted a 'cout', and I know the file is opened and closed. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong for the code not to read the contents of the .txt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "option_class.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
double cprice = 0.0;
int i = 0;
string line;
ifstream is;
is.open("/Users/<USER>/Desktop/SPY.txt");
if (!is){
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    return(0);
}
while(!getline(is, line).eof()){
    is >> cprice;
    option1.price.push_back(cprice);
}
is.close();
cout << "Closing file" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to print cprice?

Comment: `if (!is)` -> `if (!is.is_open())`

Comment: How do you know the vector size is zero? The code shown never inspects it.

Comment: `while(!getline(is, line).eof())` -> `while (is >> cprice)`

Comment: see also:  "Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?"  at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/2785528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something simpler:

```
while (is >> cprice)
{
    option1.price.push_back(cprice);
}
```

The `operator>>` will skip whitespace, which includes newlines.  There is no need to read a line at a time.